# The argument 'nameOrConnectionString' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, migration, iis-8, iis-10

I am trying to migrate a web application in mvc from iis 8 to iis 10, the entire folder from the old server was copied and mounted as is, only with the updated connection string

some solutions i found only refer settings in the appsettings.json but the project is still managed with web.config

the app run the login, when try to connect to bd trhow the error

## The argument 'nameOrConnectionString' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRs3I.jpg)

rebuild the project, change the framework target, change the visual studio version no works

Comment: You did not provide relevant configuration file code. Please double-check the updated connection string to ensure it is spelled correctly and uses the necessary database credentials. After making any changes to the web.config file or application pool configuration, it is best to restart IIS to ensure the changes take effect.